# Oculus LibOVR and GLEW header conflicts

Tags: opengl, glew, include-path, oculus

Oculus PC SDK Version: 0.6.0.1

Windows Visual Studios 2010

I'm trying to adapt an existing OpenGL application for the Oculus DK2. What I have currently working and tested:

1. Oculus SDK Sample: OculusRoomTiny(GL)
2. OpenGL application composed of Rendering Library that depends on GLEW and simple front-end to handle context, inputs, and window that relies on GLUT.

I'm currently trying to build a new project that replaces the OculusRoomTiny rendering code with my Rendering Library. There is now a conflict between the glew header(glew.h) and a header within the Oculus SDK(CAPI_GLE_GL.h). Whichever header I include first, I'll get an error from the other when it gets included later on:

- LONG_PATH_TO\glew.h(84): fatal error C1189: #error :  gl.h included before glew.h
- LONG_PATH_TO\ovr_sdk_win_0.6.0.1\oculussdk\libovrkernel\src\gl\CAPI_GLE_GL.h(55): fatal error C1189: #error :  gl.h should be included after this, not before.

Also, in the comments of "CAPI_GLE.h", that includes "CAPI_GLE_GL.h"

```
// This file provides functionality similar to a reduced version of GLEW, plus some
// additional functionality that's useful to us, such as function hooking.
```

This leads me to believe that the Oculus SDK libraries and GLEW are incompatible, but I have found no source to confirm it. I have found code samples that use GLEW and the Oculus SDK that seem to counter this reasoning, but they only use previous version of the SDK(0.3/0.4) before the Direct HMD Access display mode was added.

- Are GLEW and the Oculus SDK 0.6.0.1 incompatible?
- Why are they incompatible / Why does the Oculus SDK supply their own "version" of GLEW?

Comment: You should not be including `CAPI_GLE_GL.h`.  It's an internal SDK file that's not for use by the public.  You should include `OVR_CAPI_GL.h`.

Comment: The Oculus SDK Sample OculusRoomTiny(GL) includes it within Win32_GLAppUtil.h. I just tried replacing CAPI_GLE_GL.h with glew.h and the glew.dll but got ~20 undeclared identifiers.

Comment: It does seem like they are incompatible (because they serve the same purpose). Would love for some clarification also.