# Using a single float texture in OpenGL with the Oculus SDK

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, oculus

I'm using the Oculus SDK version 1.8.0 (with OpenGL 4.5).
But I’m unsure how I need to change the following line, which works for a 4 uchar image:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 1280, 720, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

I would change the first GL_RGBA to GL_R32F (see doc), the 2nd to GL_RED since it’s one channel and GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE to GL_FLOAT:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32F, 1280, 720, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
```

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml

But **GL_R32F is not available for me in the Oculus SDK**. Can you give me any pointers? I've looked for the definition of it in the SDK, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: What does the Oculus SDK have to do with OpenGL here? You can't *display* a floating-point texture to any display device, Oculus or otherwise.

Comment: I am not displaying it - I am passing it to a shader to modify my geometry. The float texture is given to me via hardware. 

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think in "CAPI_GLE_GL.h" the Oculus SDK defines a minimal wrapper for OpenGL support, which intercepts OpenGL calls basically. The specified "sized internal format" is not available to me.

Comment: As [said here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686884/oculus-libovr-and-glew-header-conflicts#comment51322174_31686884), "You should not be including CAPI_GLE_GL.h. It's an internal SDK file that's not for use by the public. You should include OVR_CAPI_GL.h."

Comment: But when I replaced the the include, I lose all OpenGL declarations like GLuints and GL_TEXTURE_2D. Is there an OpenGL header provided for that? Or do I need to use something like glew?

Comment: The Oculus SDK does not exist to provide you with access to OpenGL. You're supposed to do that on your own, with whatever tools you would use without Oculus.